# Which python version needs from __future__ import with_statement?

Tags: python, python-import

Using python 2.6.5, I can use the `with` statement without calling `from __future__ import with_statement`. How can I tell which version of Python supports `with` without specifically importing it from `__future__`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`__future__` features are self-documenting.  Try this:

```
>>> from __future__ import with_statement
>>> with_statement.getOptionalRelease()
(2, 5, 0, 'alpha', 1)
>>> with_statement.getMandatoryRelease()
(2, 6, 0, 'alpha', 0)
```

These respectively indicate the first release supporting `from __future__ import with_statement` and the first release to support it without using `from __future__`.

Also, read this:

```
>>> import __future__
>>> help(__future__)
```

Answer (score 17):

You only need it in Python 2.5. Older versions (<= 2.4) don't support it and newer versions (>= 2.6) have it enabled by default.

So if you want to support Python >= 2.5, you can simply put the `from __future__ import with_statement` at the beginning. For newer versions, it will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:

```
New in version 2.5.
```