# Can I import sorted using from __future__ in Jython?

Tags: python, jython, sorting

I am stuck using the older version (2.2.1) of Jython on the machines I am working on, but I need the sorted method. I already import generators from **future**, but

```
from __future__ import sorted
```

returns SyntaxError: future feature sorted is not defined. Is there a module I can import that has it?

Comment: `2.2.1`? Jeez. Spend time on upgrading Jython instead of hacking with an old version.

Comment: FYI, this is what can be imported from future: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792223/235698

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're stuck with an old version of jython, maybe you should use `.sort()` instead?

```
>>> a = [ 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 ]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

You could even define your own sorted to replace the missing one:

```
>>> def my_sorted(a):
...     a = list(a)
...     a.sort()
...     return a
... 
>>> b = [3,1,4,1,5,9]
>>> my_sorted(b)
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>> b
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
```