# reading and writing into file, proper indenting and syntax highlighting

Tags: python

I am trying to read from one file and write to another file using:

```
with open('example2') as inpf, open('outputrt','w') as outf:  
    for l in inpf:
        outf.write(l)
```

But I am getting a syntax error at the line 1 i.e.

`"with open('example2') as inpf, open('outputrt','w') as outf:" pointing at "inpf,"`

My python version is 2.6. Is there an error in syntax?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791903/which-python-version-need-from-future-import-with-statement (short version: add `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of your script).

Comment: If this is really your code, you would be better off with `shutil.copyfile`.

Comment: This code works for me .. Python 2.7.2

Comment: with is working fine if i give only the part till inpf, but if i give it together with output file in write mode, i am geting syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is only supported in 2.7+.
In 2.6 you can do:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.nested(open('example2'), open('outputrt','w')) as (inpf, outf):  
    for l in inpf:
        outf.write(l)
```

Or it might look cleaner to you to do this (this would be my preference):

```
with open('example2') as inpf:
    with open('outputrt','w') as outf:  
        for l in inpf:
            outf.write(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python versons <= 2.6, you can use

```
inPipe = open("example2", "r")
outPipe = open("outputrt", "w")
for k in inPipe:
    outPipe.write(k)
```