# The right strategy for printing formatted strings from a single Python script, in both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I know I'm quite late with all this, but I have a relatively simple command-line Python script, written for 2.7, which I'd like to make usable on both Python 2.7+ and Python 3+. Since it's a single script:

- I do not want to use [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) - while `six` is just a single file, now I'd have to take care of two files (the `six` module and my script), instead of one
- I do not want to use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/pyporting.html#support-python-2-7); because then again I'd have to take care of two files (the 2.7 version of my script and the 3.2 version of it), instead of one

So, I thought the best approach for me would be [to write Python 2.x as much compatible with Python 3.x as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498823/how-to-write-python-2-x-as-much-compatible-with-python-3-x-as-possible); then I could code once, and not worry if I have to run the script on a USB-thumbdrive OS, which may *only* have Python 2.7 (or for that matter, *only* Python 3+), and which I may have trouble finding and/or installing the right version of Python for.

To demonstrate my problems, here is a sample script based on examples in [Learning Python -- Sample chapter 9: Common Tasks in Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lpython/chapter/ch09.html) - and the preparation in `bash` on Ubuntu 11.04 (with a bit of Unicode, to spice it up):

```
cd /tmp

mkdir /tmp/ptest
echo 'Байхъусут, зæрæдтæ!.. Байхъусут, лæппутæ!..' > /tmp/ptest/test.txt
echo 'Байхъусут, зæрæдтæ!.. Байхъусут, лæппутæ!..
Байхъусут зарæгмæ, фыдæлты кадæгмæ,
Дзæбæхдæр бахъырнут уæ бæзджын хъæлæстæй!..' > /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt

cat > tscript.py <<"EOF"
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import fileinput, sys, string, os

if ( len(sys.argv) > 3 ) or ( len(sys.argv) < 2 ):
  print "Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "searchterm [path]"
  sys.exit()

# take the first argument out of sys.argv and assign it to searchterm
searchterm, sys.argv[1:] = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:]

if len(sys.argv) == 1:                  # if no dir is specified,
  indir = os.curdir                     #   use current dir
else:                                   # otherwise, use dir specified
  indir = sys.argv[1]                   #   on the command line

filenames = [indir+"/"+f for f in os.listdir(indir) if os.path.isfile(indir+"/"+f)]

for line in fileinput.input(filenames):
  num_matches = string.count(line, searchterm)
  if num_matches:                     # a nonzero count means there was a match
    print "found '%s' %d times in %s on line " % ( searchterm, num_matches, fileinput.filename() ), \
      fileinput.filelineno()
EOF
```

Trying this:

```
$ python2.7 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/test.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 1 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  2

$ python3.2 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
  File "tscript.py", line 17
    print "Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "searchterm [path]"
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Ok, that must be the change of print - will just adding parenthesis do? I change like this:

```
  print ("Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "searchterm [path]")
  ....
    print ("found '%s' %d times in %s on line " % ( searchterm, num_matches, fileinput.filename() ), \
      fileinput.filelineno() )
```

... will that do?:

```
$ python3.2 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tscript.py", line 31, in <module>
    num_matches = string.count(line, searchterm)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Nope.. so I also change this line:

```
  num_matches = line.count(searchterm) # string.count(line, searchterm)
```

... is that enough? Well - somewhat, it seems:

```
$ python3.2 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/test.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 1 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  2
$ python2.7 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
("found '\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x85\xd1\x8a\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x83\xd1\x82' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/test.txt on line ", 1)
("found '\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x85\xd1\x8a\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x83\xd1\x82' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x85\xd1\x8a\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x83\xd1\x82.txt on line ", 1)
("found '\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x85\xd1\x8a\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x83\xd1\x82' 1 times in /tmp/ptest/\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x85\xd1\x8a\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x83\xd1\x82.txt on line ", 2)
```

Now at least it doesn't crash - but the python 2.7 `print` sees a tuple, and apparently it doesn't by default decode the string inside that tuple right ...

So, apparently, now I want to import `print_function` from `__future__` for python 2.7 ([Which python version needs from __future__ import with_statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791903/which-python-version-needs-from-future-import-with-statement)); so I try to put this at the top of the file (after the `coding` statement), thinking that I better try to use the import only for 2.x version:

```
import __future__, sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
  from __future__ import print_function
else:
  pass
```

... but I get:

```
$ python2.7 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
  File "tscript.py", line 6
    from __future__ import print_function
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

The answer to this, in the question [Python graceful future feature (__future__) import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388069/python-graceful-future-feature-future-import) is to use a wrapper `.py` file - but then, I have the same problem again of having to think of two files, instead of one.

I thought I could cheat like this - even if it does create an extra file:

```
import __future__, sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
  str = """from __future__ import print_function"""
  f = open('compat23.py','w')
  f.write(str)
  f.close()
  import compat23
  print("sys.version_info[0] < 3", end='(')
else:
  print("sys.version_info[0] >= 3", end=')')
```

... but that doesn't matter really:

```
$ python2.7 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
  File "tscript.py", line 11
    print("sys.version_info[0] < 3", end='(')
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

... because the `__future__` import was valid only for the scope of newly-created `compat23` module, apparently.

So:

- I am apparently making a mistake trying to limit `__future__` import only to versions below 3, given that `from __future__ ...` is a compile-time statement; but then:
- How does Python 3 react to this statement? Does it simply get ignored?
- What happens then, when in Python 4 they decide to deprecate `print` again - wouldn't then `from __future__ import print_function` have a meaning again in Python 3, even if it may be ignored in Python 3 currently?

So, I guess, if I want to avoid thinking about this, and still use a single-file only script, I'm down to the advice in [noconv.html](http://python3porting.com/noconv.html#supporting-the-print-function): "*... or you can use a separate print function that works under both Python 2 and Python 3 .. the trick is to use sys.stdout.write() and formatting ....*"; also seen in [Eli Bendersky's website » Making code compatible with Python 2 and 3](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/05/19/making-code-compatible-with-python-2-and-3/).

And so I try with this at start of the file, instead of the `__future__` import part - and change the corresponding print statements:

```
def printso(*inargs):
  outstr = ""
  for inarg in inargs:
    outstr += str(inarg) + " "
  outstr += "\n"
  sys.stdout.write(outstr)
```

....
      printso ("Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "searchterm [path]")
      ....
        printso ("found '%s' %d times in %s on line " % ( searchterm, num_matches, fileinput.filename() ), \
          fileinput.filelineno() )

... and this does, indeed, work fine in both python 2.7 and 3.2:

```
$ python2.7 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/test.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 1 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  2
$ python3.2 tscript.py Байхъусут /tmp/ptest
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/test.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 2 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  1
found 'Байхъусут' 1 times in /tmp/ptest/Байхъусут.txt on line  2
```

OK, but now it turns out that percent sign `%` for string formatting is deprecated as well; so instead I should write:

```
  #printso ("found '%s' %d times in %s on line " % ( searchterm, num_matches, fileinput.filename() ), \
  #  fileinput.filelineno() )
  printso ("found '{0}' {1} times in {2} on line ".format(searchterm, num_matches, fileinput.filename() ), \
    fileinput.filelineno() )
```

Thankfully, this works for both 2.7 and 3.2, and in [New Python 3.0 string formatting - really necessary? - comp.lang.python | Google Groups](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_skFveO0NIkJ:http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/23d63689c0087ebf/%2Bpython3+percent+string&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a&hl=en&ct=clnk) it is stated:

> >> You can use the old 2.x syntax also in Python 3.x:
>
> > Yeah, but it's deprecated, and - as I understand it - may be removed
>   > completely in future versions. Also, in the future, if you are working
>   > with code from another developer, it's likely that developer will use
>   > the new format. I suppose you can use both - but what an awful mess
>   > that would be.
>
> It's not going to be removed for many years - if ever.

... however, who can be sure for how long this will stay true, given it's deprecated?

So, essentially - I would like to confirm:

- How does `from __future__ import` behave in Python 3? What when Python 4 comes about, and the Python 3 at that time contains deprecated features, which will have to be imported from "future" Python 4?
- for a script of this character, which I want to keep in single `.py` file, and compatible for both Python 2.7 and (hopefully) 3+: am I better off writing my own `print` function based on `sys.stdout.write`, and using that everywhere, instead of messing with `__future__`?
- Am I also better off using the new string formatting syntax everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Python's `__from__ future import feature` statement  is forwards compatible. That is, even if `feature` becomes standard in a future release, the import statement is still legal.

So rather than doing a bunch of work to get your own `print` function to work, just unconditionally put this at the top of your file (before any other code):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

It will just work, forever.